# How to update java doc libraries?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm running NetBeans 6.9 SE and I'd like to use Persistance API. I can view it online, but internet access is not always available, therefore I'd like to download that part of API on my laptop.

I understand that to add it I need to go to Library Manager, pick a library and point javadoc to correct zip/folder.

Can somebody please tell me how to download that either entire API or at least Persistance api to my local machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should be able to find this stuff on one of Oracle's sites. The Persistence API is usually bundled with Glassfish but in this case they also released a standlaone version you can find here: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/persistence/JavaPersistence.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that doesn't provide a downloadable ZIP which I can use in NetBeans.

Comment: That page has every version of the code as a downloadable jar file. If you don't want the source files, grab V2.1_build_b60f under GlassFish v2.1 branch and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still having trouble, you can get the entire JavaEE API (including javax.persistence) at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/apis-139520.html

The link is entitled "Download the Java EE 6 API Specifications".  I linked to the main page, because that is a good place to start for any JavaEE documentation.

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.0 is also known as JSR 317. You can go to [JCP page](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=317) and download specification in PDF format as well as "specification for building an implementation". There you will get zip file with all classes you need. However you might also want to download some JPA implementation, for example Hibernate, EclipseLink or OpenJPA. BTW - OpenJPA has really good documentation, that coverers both - api and implementation details.